# Derivative of smooth function change sign infinitely on [0,1]?

Tags: real-analysis, morse-theory

Can the derivative $f^\prime$ of a smooth function $f\in C^\infty[0,1]$ change sign infinitely many times (or $f$ have infinitely many isolated critical points)? If yes, how about an analytic function over a closed finite interval or more generally—what do I need to assume about $f$ in order to exclude this possibility? If no, can I get away with $f\in C^k[0,1]$ for some finite $k$. Also, out of curiosity: do you know of a term for functions whose image never change sign?

Comment: Are you asking about a term for functions that never change sign, or whose derivative never changes sign? The former I'd just call "positive" or "negative", depending. For the latter of course we have "monotonic".

Comment: Functions that never change sign. Positive or negative are good, self-explaining terms.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, for example $f(x)=e^{-1/x}\sin(1/x)$. No for analytic functions -- such function has all derivatives equal to zero at accumulating point of its zeroes.